# Pyspark Impala jdbc Driver does not support this optional feature

Tags: jdbc, pyspark, spark-streaming, cloudera, impala

I am using pyspark for spark streaming. I am able to stream and create the dataframe properly with no issues. I was also able to insert data into Impala table created with only a few(5) sampled columns out of the overall columns(72) in the message from Kafka. But when I create a new a table with proper data types and columns, similarly the dataframe now has all the columns mentioned in the message of Kafka stream. I get the below exception.

> java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: [Cloudera]JDBC Driver does not support this optional feature.
>           at com.cloudera.impala.exceptions.ExceptionConverter.toSQLException(Unknown Source)
>           at com.cloudera.impala.jdbc.common.SPreparedStatement.checkTypeSupported(Unknown Source)
>           at com.cloudera.impala.jdbc.common.SPreparedStatement.setNull(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.savePartition(JdbcUtils.scala:627)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$saveTable$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:782)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$saveTable$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:782)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$29.apply(RDD.scala:926)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$29.apply(RDD.scala:926)
>           at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2064)
>           at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2064)
>           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
>           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
>           at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

I have searched a lot on this, but could not find any solution on this. I enabled debug logs as well, still it won't mention what feature does the driver not support. 
Any help or proper guidance would be appreciated. 
Thank you

## Version details :

pyspark : 2.2.0
Kafka : 0.10.2
Cloudera : 5.15.0
Cloudera Impala : 2.12.0-cdh5.15.0
Cloudera Impala JDBC driver : 2.6.4

The code I have used :

```
import json
from pyspark import SparkContext,SparkConf,HiveContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession,Row
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
from pyspark.sql.types import *

conf = SparkConf().setAppName("testkafkarecvstream")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 10)
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("testkafkarecvstream").getOrCreate()
jdbcUrl = "jdbc:impala://hostname:21050/dbName;AuthMech=0;"

fields = [
                 StructField("column_name01", StringType(), True),
                 StructField("column_name02", StringType(), True),
                 StructField("column_name03", DoubleType(), True),
                 StructField("column_name04", StringType(), True),
                 StructField("column_name05", IntegerType(), True),
                 StructField("column_name06", StringType(), True),
                  .....................
                 StructField("column_name72", StringType(), True),
]

schema = StructType(fields)

def make_rows(parts):
    customRow = Row(column_name01=datatype(parts['column_name01']),
                              .....,
                              column_name72=datatype(parts['column_name72'])
                           )
    return customRow


def createDFToParquet(rdd):
    try:
        df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd,schema)
        df.show()df.write.jdbc(jdbcUrl,
                            table="table_name",
                            mode="append",)
    except Exception as e:
        print str(e)


zkNode = "zkNode_name:2181"
topic = "topic_name"

# Reciever method
kvs = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc,
                              zkNode,
                              "consumer-group-id",
                              {topic:5},
                              {"auto.offset.reset" : "smallest"})

lines = kvs.map(lambda x: x[1])
conv = lines.map(lambda x: json.loads(x))
table = conv.map(makeRows)
table.foreachRDD(createDFToParquet)

table.pprint()

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

Comment: Are you trying to define a Array or struct?

Comment: Can you show some code you tried so far? Also, what version of `JDBC` are you using for `Impala`?

Comment: Q : Are you trying to define a Array or struct?
I have defined an array for the schema.

Q : Also, what version of JDBC are you using for Impala?
A : Cloudera Impala JDBC driver : 2.6.4